# Moving from a single IIS to a webfarm using NLB with minimal downtime?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, high-availability, nlb

Say the IP of our website is 1.1.1.1, and we want to set up NLB, is it best to set 1.1.1.1 as the virtual IP - could mess this up and cause downtime...

Better to set the virtual IP as 1.1.1.2, then once verified the NLB works, change the DNS to point the A record to 1.1.1.2 instead of 1.1.1.1?

Is there another solution, how would you do this?

Comment: As long as you have an extra IP: the latter is the best, that way all those with not yet updated dns records can still reach the site on 1.1.1.1

Comment: thanks, if you put that as an answer I'd be able to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the second ip. When you are getting ready to make the move lower the TTL on your A record. After the move has been completed successfully you can raise the TTL backup up.